# ¿Cómo "deformar" los ejes de un gráfico en plt python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

estoy trazando algunas funciones en python con la biblioteca plt, algunas de estas funciones tienen un pequeño intervalo de variabilidad en un eje (de -0.06 a 0.01 por ejemplo) pero en el otro eje el intervalo es más grande. Entonces, cuando grafico tres de estas funciones juntas, obtuve como resultado líneas rectas, mi pregunta es, ¿hay alguna forma de 'deformar' solo una parte del eje para obtener el detalle que necesito?
Adjunto algunas de las imágenes.
Gracias por tu atención.

[image: Imagen con buen detalle]
[image: Líneas rectas]

Comment: Podrias añadir los datos para hacer el mismo grafico? Entiendo que usar el eje x como logaritmico no sirve, por tanto lo único que me viene a la cabeza es hacer dos subplots, uno con el eje entre -0.005 y 0 y otro entre 0 y 3

Answer (score 1):

Un modo de aconseguir ejes deformados es usar 2 subplots, uno para cada rango de interés.

De este modo, los pasos a seguir son basicamente:

1. Generar los subplots y graficar los datos en ambos
2. Fijar los limites de los ejes deseados para cada subplot
3. Eliminar los ejes y ticks sobrantes y eliminar el espacio entre subplots
4. Si se desea, añadir un indicador donde la escala de los ejes varia. En el ejemplo una línea diagonal

Debajo hay un ejemplo de codigo para conseguir este efecto.

```
# Generar los datos para el plot de ejemplo
y1 = np.linspace(12,0)
x1 = np.sin(np.linspace(np.pi,9/2*np.pi))*.005-0.004
x2 = np.linspace(x1[0],3)
y2 = np.ones_like(x2)*y1[0]


fig,(ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

# hacer el plot de los datos en ambos axes
ax.plot(x1, y1)
ax.plot(x2, y2)
ax2.plot(x1, y1)
ax2.plot(x2, y2)

# seleccionar que rango debe contener cada parte
ax.set_xlim(-0.02,0.02) 
ax2.set_xlim(0.02,3) 

# ocultar las lineas y ticks entre ax y ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.tick_left() # fijar los ticks a la izquierda de ax
ax2.yaxis.tick_right() # fijar los ticks a la derecha de ax2, sino quedan enmedio


# eliminar el espacio entre subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

# Si se desea, se puede añadir una linea diagonal para marcar la deformacion del eje
d = .015 
kwargs = dict(transform=ax2.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax2.plot((-d,d),(-d,+d), **kwargs) # diagonal superior
ax2.plot((-d,d),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs) # diagonal inferior
```

Que genera el siguiente grafico:

[image: ejes deformados]